# ¿Cómo mover un archivo binario desde la base de datos a una carpeta?

Tags: php, mysql

Tengo una tabla en mi base de datos. Esta tabla contiene 3 campos

- ID
- Nombre archivo
- Archivo (binario)

Cómo puedo descargar este archivo binario y moverlo a un directorio en mi computadora.

Aquí está el codigo :

```
 <?php
function download($id){

include('conectar.php');

  if (!$conexio_bd=conectar_bdBonita('bonita','bpm','bonita')){
  echo"Imposible conectarse a la base de datos Bonita: ".mysqli_connect_error();
  }
  $consulta = mysqli_query($conexio_bd, "SELECT * from document where id='".$id."'");
  mysqli_set_charset($conexio_bd,'utf-8');

       list($id, $file, $type, $size,$content) =   mysqli_fetch_array($consulta);

         header("Content-length: $size");
         header("Content-type: $type");
         header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$file");
        // ob_clean();
         //flush();

         mysqli_close($conexio_bd);
         exit;
       }

       download(3504);
    ?>
```

Comment: ¿Puedes mostrarnos que has intentado o avanzado?

Comment: Agrega el código a la pregunta (editándola), por favor.

Comment: no pude poner mas codigo porque no me deja!

Comment: donde se puede editar la pregunta ..no encuentro la opcion?

Comment: @programer Haz click en el boton [Editar](http://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/16626/edit) al pie la pregunta y agrega el código.

Comment: gracias , y a lo he editado, espero que se entienda!

Comment: Alguien sabe como puedo solucionarlo???, please es Urgente!!

Answer (score 1):

Según veo te falta escribir el contenido del archivo:

```
 <?php
function download($id){
  include('conectar.php');

  if (!$conexio_bd=conectar_bdBonita('bonita','bpm','bonita')) {
    echo"Imposible conectarse a la base de datos Bonita: ".mysqli_connect_error();
  }

  $consulta = mysqli_query($conexio_bd, "SELECT * from document where id='".$id."'");

  mysqli_set_charset($conexio_bd,'utf-8');

  list($id, $file, $type, $size,$content) =   mysqli_fetch_array($consulta);

  header("Content-length: $size");
  header("Content-type: $type");
  header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$file");

  echo $content;


  // ob_clean();
  //flush();

  mysqli_close($conexio_bd);
  exit;
}

download(3504);
```

Comment: El contenido del archivo esta en el campo de la base de datos, y puede ser un archivo PDF, XLS, DOC..etc, no se a que te refieres exactamente?

Comment: mira la linea sobre `ob_clean()` , a eso me refiero

Comment: Estoy muy confuso!..simplemente lo que quiero es descargar el archivo que esta en el campo archivo de la base de datos, y después moverlo a una carpeta o directorio local. ..desconozco si se puede mover directamente desde la base de datos a la carpeta local sin descargarlo primero.

Comment: @programer creo que falta explicitar mejor tu pregunta. Según entiendo a partir de tú código, estás intentando hacer un script en PHP que te permita descargar los archivos guardados en alguna tabla mysql. De acuerdo a eso, te indiqué el problema que tiene tu script y como solucionarlo. Ahora, si lo que deseas es bajar todos los archivos de una sola vez, se puede hacer una infinidad de cosas distintas: bajar un dump y en base a eso correr en local un script; hacer un script para que saque los archivos y los comprima en zip,etc. Por favor, deja un poco más claro cual es tu duda.